# Implementing DI with UnitOfWork and repository patterns in winform use autofac (Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException HResult=0x80131500)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-core, autofac, unit-of-work

So let's start with DbContext

```
  public class SIMContext : DbContext
  {
    public SIMContext()
    {
       
    }
    public SIMContext(DbContextOptions<SIMContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SIMContext"].ConnectionString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new DepartmentConfiguration());
    } 
}
```

And this is my IUnitOfWork:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IDepartmentRepository Departments { get; }
    int Complete();
}
```

And This is UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{

    private readonly SIMContext _context;
    public UnitOfWork(SIMContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        Departments = new DepartmentRepository(_context);
    }
    public IDepartmentRepository Departments { get; private set; }
    public int Complete()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

And this is my IRepository:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(object id);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync();
    Task<TEntity> FindAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, string[] includes = null);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindAllAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, string[] includes = null);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindAllAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, int take, int skip);
    Task<TEntity> SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
    void Remove(TEntity entity);
    void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
}
```

And this is my Repository:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        dbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    public async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        await dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
        return entity;
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        await dbSet.AddRangeAsync(entities);
        return entities;
    }
    public async Task<TEntity> FindAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, string[] includes = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
        if (includes != null)
            foreach (var incluse in includes)
                query = query.Include(incluse);

        return await query.SingleOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindAllAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, string[] includes = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (includes != null)
            foreach (var include in includes)
                query = query.Include(include);

        return await query.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindAllAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, int take, int skip)
    {
        return await dbSet.Where(predicate).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToListAsync();
    }
    public async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(object id)
    {
        return await dbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await dbSet.ToListAsync();
    }
    public void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
         dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
         dbSet.RemoveRange(entities);
    }
    public async Task<TEntity> SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await dbSet.SingleOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
    }
}
```

and this is IDepartmentRepository :

```
public interface IDepartmentRepository: IRepository<Department>
{
}
```

and this is DepartmentRepository :

```
 public class DepartmentRepository : Repository<Department>, IDepartmentRepository
{
    public DepartmentRepository(SIMContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    public SIMContext SIMContext
    {
        get { return Context as SIMContext; }
    }
}
```

And this is my Program class :

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static IContainer Container;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Container = Configure();
        Application.Run(new XtraMain(Container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>()));
    }
    static IContainer Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>();
        builder.RegisterType<XtraMain>();
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

and this is my XtraMain form :

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    public XtraMain(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    private void bbtnDepartment_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Frm_Department frme = new(unitOfWork)
        {
            Name = "Frm_Department"

        };
        ViewChildForm(frme);
    }
```

but when I run the program I get error in this line:

```
Application.Run(new XtraMain(Container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>()));
```

The error is :

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=An exception was thrown while activating Smart_Industrial_Management.Persistence.UnitOfWork.
> Source=Autofac
> StackTrace:
> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ExecuteOperation(ResolveRequest request) at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
> at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
> at Smart_Industrial_Management.Program.Main() in C:\Users\MBoua\source\repos\SIM Windows7 EF Core5\Smart Industrial Management\Program.cs:line 49
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
> Inner Exception 1:
> DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Smart_Industrial_Management.Persistence.UnitOfWork' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
> Cannot resolve parameter 'Smart_Industrial_Management.Persistence.SIMContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Smart_Industrial_Management.Persistence.SIMContext)'.

How can I solve this problem?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Smart_Industrial_Management.Persistence.UnitOfWork' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'Smart_Industrial_Management.Persistence.SIMContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Smart_Industrial_Management.Persistence.SIMContext)'.

It looks like you haven't register `SIMContext` when configuring the Autofac. Adding the following registration in your `Configure` method may help:

```
builder.RegisterType<SIMContext>().AsSelf();
```